# Split one row into multiple rows of dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to convert one row from dataframe into multiple rows. If hours is same then rows will not get split but if hour is different then rows will split into multiple rows wrt difference between hours.I am good with solution using dataframe function or hive query.

Input Table or Dataframe
[image]

Expected Output Table or Dataframe
[image]

**Please help me to get workaround for expected output.**

Comment: Can you share what you've already tried?

Comment: prepare a data sample using scala instead of screen shots someone will usethat and try to give answers. if you put excel or screen shots its double effort for the answerers . hope you understood.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution for such a simple schema is to use [Dataset.flatMap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) after defining case classes for the input and output schema.

A simple UDF solution would return a sequence and then you can use `functions.explode`. Far less clean & efficient that using `flatMap`.

Last but not least, you could create your own table-generating UDF but that would be extreme overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own logic inside the `map` operation and use `flatMap` to achieve this.

**The following is the crude way, that I have implemented the solution, you can improvise it as per the need.**

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
import java.time.{Duration, LocalDateTime}

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

import sparkSession.sqlContext.implicits._

val df = Seq(("john", "2/9/2018", "2/9/2018 5:02", "2/9/2018 5:12"),
    ("smit", "3/9/2018", "3/9/2018 6:12", "3/9/2018 8:52"),
    ("rick", "4/9/2018", "4/9/2018 23:02", "5/9/2018 2:12")
  ).toDF("UserName", "Date", "start_time", "end_time")

val rdd = df.rdd.map(row => {
  val result = new ArrayBuffer[Row]()
  val formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy H:m")
  val formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy H:mm")

  val d1 = LocalDateTime.parse(row.getAs[String]("start_time"), formatter1)
  val d2 = LocalDateTime.parse(row.getAs[String]("end_time"), formatter1)

  if (d1.getHour == d2.getHour) result += row
  else {
    val hoursDiff = Duration.between(d1, d2).toHours.toInt

    result += Row.fromSeq(Seq(
      row.getAs[String]("UserName"),
      row.getAs[String]("Date"),
      row.getAs[String]("start_time"),
      d1.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS).withMinute(0).format(formatter2)))

    for (index <- 1 until hoursDiff) {
      result += Row.fromSeq(Seq(
        row.getAs[String]("UserName"),
        row.getAs[String]("Date"),
        d1.plus(index, ChronoUnit.HOURS).withMinute(0).format(formatter1),
        d1.plus(1 + index, ChronoUnit.HOURS).withMinute(0).format(formatter2)))
    }

    result += Row.fromSeq(Seq(
      row.getAs[String]("UserName"),
      row.getAs[String]("Date"),
      d2.withMinute(0).format(formatter2),
      row.getAs[String]("end_time")))
  }
  result
}).flatMap(_.toIterator)

rdd.collect.foreach(println)
```

and finally, your result is as follows:

```
[john,2/9/2018,2/9/2018 5:02,2/9/2018 5:12]
[smit,3/9/2018,3/9/2018 6:12,3/9/2018 7:00]
[smit,3/9/2018,3/9/2018 7:0,3/9/2018 8:00]
[smit,3/9/2018,3/9/2018 8:00,3/9/2018 8:52]
[rick,4/9/2018,4/9/2018 23:02,5/9/2018 0:00]
[rick,4/9/2018,5/9/2018 0:0,5/9/2018 1:00]
[rick,4/9/2018,5/9/2018 1:0,5/9/2018 2:00]
[rick,4/9/2018,5/9/2018 2:00,5/9/2018 2:12]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked with few modification.